# Can this coffeescripts method be simplified?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescripts. Can the `getSum` method be simplified more? Thanks

```
MyObject =
  checkCondition: (num) ->
    return true if num is 5

  getSum: (num) ->
    total = 0
    total += i for i in [1..num] when @checkCondition i
    total
```

I tried removing the last total but coffeescripts compiler goes nut :-/

Any help greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, `return true if num is 5` is the same as just `num is 5`.
Then, you can convert the explicit loop into a `reduce` (you can read about it in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):

```
MyObject =
  checkCondition: (num) -> num is 5

  getSum: (num) ->
    [0..num].reduce (x,y) =>
        if @checkCondition y then x + y else x
```

Note `=>` instead of plain `->` after `(x,y)`. This is [fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow), it prevents the capture of `@` the inside function.

Comment: Using `reduce` is definitely the most elegant approach, but note that it's not supported in older browsers. You can either add it to the `Array` prototype yourself, or use the excellent [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library.

Answer (score 1):

As written getSum will only ever return 0 or 5, but I assume this checkCondition is merely an example, so here is my answer:

```
MyObject =
  checkCondition: (num) -> num is 5

  getSum: (num) ->
    total = (i for i in [1..num] when @checkCondition i).reduce ((x, y) -> x + y), 0
```

Comment: That is one liner even I don't understand how reduce works

Comment: nice implementation

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

The `getSum` method looks fine. The `checkCondition` is overcomplicated: it better be `checkCondition: (num) -> num is 5`

Comment: actually the checkCondition code was a long one but it is not important here.. I just want to know if it is possible to further simplify `getSum` to one line?